# PHP SESSION dies on iPad when plugged into power. Chrome App

Tags: php, session, ipad, google-chrome-app

I have a PHP mySQL site that uses SESSIONS. the users work on Forms for sometimes multiple hours. We have no issues with session timeouts, but I am receiving complaints that when they plug the iPad in during one of their form inputs, it kills the session and they have to log back in, loosing all of the data input. I am at a loss on this one. AJAX isn't an option at this time.
Any ideas on what to check?

Comment: I would prefer you to use cookies instead of session in case of any problems in any browser that is being used by any user. It totally solves the problem.

Comment: @Phiter Sessions depend on cookies. If the session is going away, the only explanation is that the cookie is being deleted. So using cookies would probably fail as well.

Comment: I'm trying to diagnose how putting a device in charge would delete cookies or something. Really strange.

Comment: @JeffB Cookies are not as secure as sessions, the user can modify the cookie data. Session data is stored on the server.

Comment: @Phiter I think sessions use a session cookie, so maybe putting the device in charge is restarting the browser and deleting all session cookies.

Comment: Can they reproduce this? Over and over again? With a brand-new session? People frequently notice meaningless coincidences and read too much into them.

Comment: @JeffB I inherited the project a few yrs back and expanded. The labor for changing to cookies inst feasible for the client. The security isn't a big issue though as the data isn't sensitive. Its inspection information. Does anyone have any idea where to even look into power killing the session? It's blowing my mind.

Comment: ceejayoz, Yes. mulitple users have stated that it happens when they plug in.

Comment: *"but I am receiving complaints that when they plug the iPad in during one of their form inputs, it kills the session"* - That sounds more like a software problem on "their" end. You could store something in a database.

Comment: *NOTE: They are using iPads with SIM cards for internet. Maybe there is something that resets the network access for a second, in turn killing the session.

Comment: ^ that sounds like we're nearing the sun's core. That comment I responded to, was deleted.

Comment: Funk Forty Niner, go 9ers...Are you suggesting changing all to AJAX, or a different solution?

Comment: @kayakerpaul I don't think that by switching over to Ajax will do anything. If the problem is in fact because they plug their iPads in, that the connection gets lost for a brief period of time. I'd store a cookie but that may end up getting deleted on their machine when the browser closes.

Comment: @kayakerpaul please remember to always use the `@username`. Some may not be present anymore.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just ran a ping utility on my iPad. I don't have the sim, but connected to WiFi. When I plug in, I don't drop connection, but response drops 200ms from 12ms. I'm leaning towards this being the issue. I will have client test and report back.

Comment: Sessions shouldn't *necessarily* go away due to a network change or 200ms ping unless you're doing something kinda funky. Do you have something that limits a session to a single IP at a time, perhaps?

Comment: Losing the connection shouldn't affect sessions. Browsers don't need to keep a persistent connection to the server. What happens if you set a session cookie, plug in, then check whether the session cookie is still there?